# Aws S3 connection with specific path

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to list and download folders from a bucket on path eg:"aaa/bbb/" using the aws-sdk gem v2. However I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I tried:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('akid', 'secret')
})        

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new

# reference an existing bucket by name
bucket = s3.bucket('aaa')

bucket.objects(prefix: '/bbb/').each do |folder|
  p folder
end
```

It says: **Access Denied (Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied)**

But, if I use the command line AWS CLI instead, and execute:

```
aws s3 ls aaa/bbb/
```

it works...

Any suggestion?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The convention in S3 is that the "root" of a bucket's keyspace is a zero-length empty string... it is not `/` as some people naturally assume.

The prefix you are looking for would be expressed as `bbb/` rather than `/bbb/`.

Comment: Thank you. That changed something, but do I need to defined any endpoint? I am getting this error: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint.

Comment: You are setting `region: 'us-west-2'` so the error suggests your bucket is in a different region.  Verify that?

Comment: You are right, region was wrong, I changed to 'us-east-1', and now I still get:  Access Denied (Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied).

Comment: Can you extract any additional information from the exception?  Some exceptions should provide explanations.  I'm unfamiliar with the Ruby SDK -- I wrote my own libraries that work directly with the API.

Comment: This is what I get: ...rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.7.3/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call': Access Denied (Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied). I will probably use the aws command line instead, If I can't make aws-sdk work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you've to put in the credentials slightly different:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('akid', 'secret')
})
```

Maybe try this to list the content of the bucket:

```
s3.list_objects(bucket:'aaa').each do |response|
  puts response.contents.map(&:key)
end
```

Comment: Yes, true. I was trying to figure out how to fix it and I ended up using another code, but I already tried and it doesn't work... I will update the post according  with the documentation, thank you.

Comment: No luck with your update. Same result, access denied. I only have access to the folder "bbb" inside the bucket "aaa", however I don't know how to get there... with the Aws console works perfectly.